# origin of the expression: kick things into long grass

Tags: etymology

What is the origin of the expression: [kick things into long grass](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/kick-something-into-the-long-grass)? I hear of it in the context of political inaction.

> to react to a difficult problem by doing something to make sure that people will forget about it rather than trying to solve it.
>
> - The decision to kick the proposals into the long grass could come back to haunt all three party leaders. (Macmillan Dictionary)

The following source suggests that [its origin](http://www.idiomcenter.com/dictionary/kick-sth-into-the-long-grass) is:

> Kick it into the long grass" is golf-derived, essentially describing a form of cheating: a player whose ball lands in the rough so as to be unplayable without adding multiple strokes to the hole can cheat by kicking the ball out-of-bounds into the really long grass and take a one-stroke penalty for a lost ball. (www.idiomcenter.com)

Other sources suggest a different [origin](http://boomtownrats.activeboard.com/t44835776/in-the-long-grass-two-meanings/)

> Geldof claims it is an old Irish saying meaning that you've been round and about only not too visible- ~Where have you been? I've been lying in the long grass. Under the radar might be an approximation. Lazing with intent.
>   (boomtownrats.activeboard)

Is there evidence of a more precise origin of the above saying?

Comment: Sounds like an outdoors version of “sweep it under the rug”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand this [British expression](https://britishisms.wordpress.com/2017/12/04/kick-push-into-the-long-grass/), you have to envision a football pitch in a rural area where only the pitch itself and a bit of touch (the field beyond the white lines) is maintained.

[image: http://wherestheteahut.blogspot.de/2011/07/marsden.html]
*Football pitch in Marsden.*

If one kicks the ball into the grass — or even better, into the wooded area in the background — not only does play stop, but a new ball would usually be brought in to continue uninterrupted play and the first ball "forgotten".

Another [source suggests](https://books.google.de/books?id=m3MEbgED8eQC&pg=PT70&lpg=PT70&dq=%22kick%20into%20the%20long%20grass%22%20idiom%20derivation&source=bl&ots=-PTWgtThNA&sig=2-3HTT262lbIIIzSAggIAUOVMgE&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiXl6ymg_3YAhVEDOwKHTG7Ac0Q6AEwEHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22kick%20into%20the%20long%20grass%22%20idiom%20derivation&f=false) a derivation from golf, not football or rugby. This would add an element of subterfuge and cheating to the expression.

Comment: Hm. ;) ... a trick young House of Commons MPs learn while playing golf with their Peers.